# Which (mobile) browsers allow styling of the page title?

Tags: css

In (most? all?) desktop browsers, styling of the html `<title>` tag has no effect.

How does this work on mobile browsers? Should I begin styling the `<title>` tag?

---

User agents *do* display the content of the `<title>` tag, both in desktop:

[image]

and mobile browsers:

[image]

The presentation of the title in these tab labels is of course determined by the design of the browser and shouldn't be influenced by a web site's style sheets.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Are you doing this on desktop browsers? I don't really see what you would style.

Comment: what makes you think any browers allows styling of the title tag? I don't see where/how you'd see any styling. are you talking font/colour?

Comment: @Veve I want to achieve nothing. I just don't want to miss unstyled elements that are visible on browsers that I have no familiarity with. For all I know, the title tag could be shown prominently on tablets. I have never used a tablet nor most kinds of smartphone either.

Comment: @atmd Titles are displayed in user agents. User agents are different, and I'm not familiar with all of them. It is quite possible that there are user agents that allow styling of the title tag and display them quite uglily if unstyled (similar to the ugly icon in some browsers if a site has no favicon, which surprisingly many sites haven't).

Comment: "Titles are displayed in user agents" I don't believe that's true at all

Comment: @atmd Huh? You must not be using tabs. See my edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most mobile browsers, the contents of the `<title>` tag by default aren't even *visible* to the user unless they choose to bookmark the site or view the open tabs.

The same is gradually becoming more and more the case with desktop browsers, also. Outside of having a `favicon` there's not a lot you can do to customise the display of your page's name in a browser title / tab name window on any device.